# WP8 Binding not updating

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a WP8 app which gets data from a website and displays them.
I chose the panorama template and Visual Studio created some default code.

What I am trying to do is, that the textblock automatically gets updated if I change the variable the text is bound to. But calling changeDate() doesn't change the UI. The textbox still says "dd.mm.yyyy".

```
MainPage.xaml:
<phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="12,0,0,38">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock
          Text="{Binding Date}"
          Style="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTextStyle}"
          Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock.DataContext>
          <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
        </TextBlock.DataContext>
      </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
```

.

```
MainViewModel.cs:
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [...]

    private string _date = "dd.mm.yyyy";
    public string Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _date;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _date)
            {
                _date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }
    }

    //public void changeDate()
    //{
    //    Date = "fu";
    //    App.ViewModel.Date = "bar";
    //}

**UPDATE 2**
    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("somelink"));
    }

    private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = FilterData(e.Result);
    }

    private string FilterData(string s)
    {
        string[] split = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(s, "<tbody>");
        s = split[1];
        split = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(s, "</tbody>");
        s = split[0];
        split = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(s, "\r\n");

        foreach(string str in split)
        {

            if (str.Contains("class=\"xl24\""))
            {
                App.ViewModel.Date = "somedate";
            }
        }

        return s;
    }
**END UPDATE 2**

[...]

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
MainPage.xaml.cs:
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = App.ViewModel;
}

**UPDATE 2**
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
    {
        App.ViewModel.LoadData();
    }
}
**END UPDATE 2**

[...]
```

.

```
App.xaml.cs:
private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

public static MainViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
            viewModel = new MainViewModel();

        return viewModel;
    }
}
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think is happening is that your **NotifyPropertyChanged** is called from some worker thread which could result in calling **Date** getter from the same worker thread. If an UI element calls data getter from worker thread (instead from Main UI thread) operation ends with "**Invalid cross-thread access**". If that's so, you should make **handler** call from Main thread. For example:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (null != handler)
    {
        Dispatcher dsp = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
        dsp.BeginInvoke(() => { 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
</TextBlock.DataContext>
```

This creates a new MainViewModel object and you are not updating this object but the one you stored in the App object.

To solve this: set the data context of the View to the App.ViewModel object (no need to set the data context of the TextBlock)

Extra: Please do NOT use this code:

```
public void changeDate()
{
    Date = "fu";
    App.ViewModel.Date = "bar";
}
```

Now your ViewModel knows about the App. Just use:

```
public void changeDate()
{
    Date = "fu";
}
```

Comment: if i remove the data context of the textblock and set "DataContext = App.ViewModel;" in the MainPage constructor, the textblock is empty

Comment: Where are you initializing the App.ViewModel? Could you post that code as well?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the added code. I suspect that somewhere in the code you create a new instance of the ViewModel. Can you show the code where you call the `changeDate` method too?

Comment: added more code to MainViewModel.cs and MainPage.xaml.cs.
on load, the viewmodel starts loading data from a website. that data gets filtered and gives the important informations (date and some other text) to the ui. the changeData() method itself doesn't exist. i tried to make it easier :)

Comment: i rewrote the whole project with the pivot template. now it works like a charm... but thank you very much.